# Print value based on multiple column

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, linq-to-sql

my table

```
+----+----------+---------+---------+----------+
| ID | State A  | State B | State C | Duration |
+----+----------+---------+---------+----------+
| 1  |     a    |    a    |    a    |    12    |
+----+----------+---------+---------+----------+
| 2  |     a    |    a    |    a    |    15    |
+----+----------+---------+---------+----------+
| 3  |     a    |    a    |    b    |    12    |
+----+----------+---------+---------+----------+
| 4  |     a    |    b    |    b    |    30    |
+----+----------+---------+---------+----------+
| 5  |     b    |    b    |    b    |    12    |
+----+----------+---------+---------+----------+
```

IF THE 3 COLUMNS AS THE SAME  VALUE AND DURATION <15 
result as the following :

```
+----+-----------------+
| ID |    THE RESULT   |
+----+-----------------+
|  1 | a is the winner |
+----+-----------------+
```

Comment: Exactly as you wrote: *the three columns have the same value and duration < 15*: `where stata_A = stateB and stateB = stateC amd duration < 15`

Comment: what about  other rows

Comment: Are you looking for a linq or an SQL solution? and if linq have you tried anything?

Comment: Then move the WHERE-condition into the Select: `case when stata_A = stateB and stateB = stateC and duration < 15 then 'is the winner' else '' end`

Answer (score 0):

This is a filter along with `concat()`:

```
select concat(statea, ' is the winner')
from t
where statea = stateb and stateb = statec and duration < 15
```

Comment: if state a =1  if state b =1  state c=1 i want some text to appear